# What technology is more reliable for web-based geotemporal data visualization?

Tags: openlayers, gis, leaflet

I have a PostGIS database with shipping tracks' data. It contains about 1 million points. Each 2D point has also a timestamp assigned.

I need to plot these in a web-map visualisation tool such as OpenLayers or Leaflet for the users to be able to perform filtering and analysis of the shipping track data. This implies me adding a time slider like [this](http://dwilhelm89.github.io/LeafletSlider/), heat maps like [this](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/visualize-points-as-a-heatmap.html), custom selection of tracks to create graphs (e.g. speed vs time, etc), load/export cvs/sph data, etc.

I have little experience in OpenLayers and none in Leaflet, although I'm keen to try new things. I'm just slightly worried about how Leaflet handles big amounts of data (if 1 million points in a map is considered "big"), and also concerned about how reliable it is for geotemporal data analytics, since it's still a tool under development and some of the things I might want in the future might not be there yet. OpenLayers has been here for longer, and it might be easier to find help and more examples.

So what is most recommendable for my case, OpenLayers or Leaflet?

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is not a complete answer but I can share some facts woth you based on my experience; I  built a geotemporal data visualization with Leaflet and KeyLines shown in [this blog post](http://keylines.com/events-and-hangouts/cyber-security-keylines).
The demo linked has not a huge dataset - the goal was to explain how to do it, rather than show off - and it is holding 15k points and 20k time events.
I've the same demo with a million data points and some more events and it plays pretty good as well as we used it for testing.

The time bar you see at the bottom is our proprietary component to handle millions of time events.

About the map and the heatmap, here's my experience:

- Leaflet is very easy to use and in few hours you have something ready. One of the main points it has is too be widely used and have a plugin eco-system to offer.
- Used Google Maps JS API and while it is rock solid it's a bit more strict on the license.
- The heatmap here is the bottleneck from my experience.

  - No Esri heatmap plugin.
  - No OpenLayers experience.

What I was looking for was a heatmap component that was able to add and remove several points all at once: as you see from the animation when we play the timebar, the heatmap gets updated pretty often.
Also, in our case it had to handle zoom in/out of data and so, so any kind of time bar interaction.

What I've tried:

- [Leaflet.heat](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat) - it is the one shown in the demo and it is pretty good. The API it's still a bit rough and there's no concept of adding an array of points. In case you have to support old browser this won't work (it's based on HTML5 Canvas).
- [heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/docs.html) - while the API looks much better than the one above I think it's a bit slower (at least from my tests). It is based on canvas as well.
- [Google Heatmap Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer) - this is the quickest solution I've found so far. The API is a bit verbose, but that is the Google Visualization API style. **This also work in older browser**.

I haven't tried the ESRI one you've linked (built on top of Leaflet.heat), but maybe it's worth to explore: they may have tweaked it to make it go faster.
In all this, no experience with OpenLayers 3 which I see includes also a Heatmap layer, so I cannot help with that.

In such demo we didn't use any database but I guess also that can be a bottleneck if not tuned properly. I cannot help on this side thought.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's very useful to know about your experience. Your demo looks very cool! If heatmaps make things complicated/slow, I might try out also [these Leaflet cluster markers](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-markercluster/), which are not the same, but requirements are flexible in this project and this still help with the data analysis. I see my question might be a bit difficult to answer since there are so many options and everybody will have a different experience. I'll work more on this after Easter, any comments in the meanwhile greatly appreciated!